# AWS IAM - allow user to create and delete service roles, but not temper with other roles

Tags: amazon-iam

I want to allow a user to create and delete service roles for specific services . I have a set of policies which I allow the user to add to the roles, so he can not escalate privileges this way. But he should not be allowed to create non-service roles and most importantly, he should not be allowed to delete or modify roles he did not create. Or at the very least, there should be a set of roles he may not touch.

Is this archivable with iam?

Comment: Hello @Nathan. I have the same difficulty. Did you solve this problem?